# how to modify the length of tab when we modify the files in bufferline.nvim

Tags: plugins, save, buffer, neovim

It's not a critical problem, but I'm asking it on Stack overflow because it's so annoying. [image: the picture of bufferline applied in neovim, see upperleft.]

The problem is that we can look only half of the circle. The circle shows when the editor modifies the file and doesn't save it. I was trying to find documents in github but failed. Also the environment is lunarvim, so I'd like to be happy if anyone reply with the configuration which can also applied in lunarvim config file. Doesn't matter if the configuration is for general environment.